# Handling multiple but SAME TYPE of exception- NoSuchElementException inside a single Try: block

Tags: python-3.x

I have data on column A of an excel sheet. I am trying to click on each element on a tool that matches text of each data item on the excel
Sometimes, for example data on cell 'A7' throw an NoSuchElementFound exception on the tool. I have written code to catch the first such exception and continue to find rest of all data items below this item whichis not found

However, how can I catch the second and subsequent same NoSuchElementFoundexceptions, when the above scenario might occur over and over  again?. I want to continue to catch the same above exceptions for every data item on the column A until I reach the last cell with data on it

Below is my code in Python 3.x:

try:

```
for i in range(3,row_ct_1 + 1,1):

    Value = ws.cell(row = i,column = 2).value

    time.sleep(5)

    x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("")     

    x.click()
```

except NoSuchElementException:

```
print(cat_1 + ' - ' + ' ' + Value + 'is not loaded on webpage.Please try
```

after some time or add it manually')

```
i = i + 1

for i in range(i,row_ct_1 + 1,1):

    Value = ws.cell(row = i ,column = 2).value

    time.sleep(5)

    x_resume = driver.find_element_by_xpath("")

    x_resume.click()
```

How Can I proceed with catching all exceptions one by one and yet continuing to search each element till end of the column A?

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution to my own issue. To solve the problem, I created a try: Except block of code and put it inside a For loop specifying the range starting from a cell number 3 on column A uptill the last cell on this column that contains data

Below is my code / solution for everybody's reference:

for i in range(3,row_ct_1 + 1,1):

```
try:
    Value = ws.cell(row = i,column = 2).value

    time.sleep(5)


    x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("")                   
    x.click()

except NoSuchElementException:

    print(cat_1 + ' - ' + ' ' + Value + 'is not loaded on webpage.Please try after some time or add it manually')
```

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

create_bt = driver.find_element_by_id("")

create_bt.click()

time.sleep(20)